# STM32: How to configure DFSDM data resolution and how does right bit shift affect?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

​

I'm currently working in a project with the Nucleo-L476RG board and the STM32CubeIDE for both development and peripherals configuration. Basically, I have a MEMS microphone (AN-000048) connected to the board. The microphone (I pretend to work in stereo mode, I only use one channel and I only have one microphone connected) sends PDM data and I use the DFSDM module get the microphone data in PCM format.

​

My problem comes with the DFSDM module configuration. By consulting documentation and videos about the module, I've arrived at some conclusions, which I use to configure the module:

​

- The clock frequency that is sent to the microphone is the Output Clock. I've configured the clock to use the system clock as source (80MHz) with a 125 divider, so I'm sending a 640KHz signal to the microphone.
- I use channel 0 with PDM/SPI input from ch0 and internal clock mode.
- I use DMA from peripheral to memory with word data width and in circular mode (which, as far as i know, involves that once the buffer is full, new data is written at the beginning of the buffer)
- I use the Filter0 with regular data injection from channel 0 in continuous mode and I have enabled both DMA and fast mode. I use a Sinc3 filter with Fosr = 16 and Iosr = 1. As far as I know and using table 159 from the RM0351, this involves that I have values between +/- 2^(log2(16^3)) = +/- 4096. That's 12 bits + 1 bit for the sign.
- As far as I know, if I send to the microphone a clock of 640Hz with my filter configuration (OSR + FOSR = 16), applying Nyquist the maximum frequency that I can sample is 20KHz = 40KHz / 2 = (640KHz / 16) / 2.

The values I get in the buffer that DFSDM uses for storing the data aren't in this range. I’ve been doing some testing about the resolution of the values that I get and I’m quite surprised. The first thing I noticed is that I don’t have negative values at all; all values in my buffer are always > 0. The second thing is that the values I have are usually arround 30-32k, which is 15 bits (without sign; 16 bits if they are signed).

However, I've read that the resolution of the DFSDM is up to 31 bits but the resolution of the output data is only up to 24 bits. I really don't understand this, but I suppose that I haven't to be concerned about that because I (theoretically) use 13 bits. I also asume that the right bit shift option is for cases where the DFSDM resolution is grater than 24 bits. Am I correct?

Regardless, if I get rid of the 8 LSB of the buffer, so i get the 24 bits that are the actual data (not quite sure about that), I don't get the resolution I expect.

Can someone please help me to understand how to set the resolution of the DFSDM data and what is the right bit shift for? What should I expect to see in the buffer that DFSDM uses to write? I've searched but I can't find any resource that helps me to understand how does it work or that leads me to the error that I'm doing (because I assume that if the data is not in the +/- 4096 range is because I'm doing something wrong).

I’m clueless about what’s happening, for me the code for getting the input data from the buffer is so simple. However, I provide some code that it may be helpful:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024    // Always FFT_SAMPLES*2
#define FFT_SAMPLES 512 // Always BUFFER_SIZE/2

DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef hdfsdm1_filter0;
DFSDM_Channel_HandleTypeDef hdfsdm1_channel0;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dfsdm1_flt0;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

int32_t Buff[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
float FFT_In[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
// More declarations but not necessary for the doubt
…

int main(void)
{

// STM32Cube Inits 

  HAL_Delay(1000);

  HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(&hdfsdm1_filter0, Buff, BUFFER_SIZE);

// Code to prepare FFT

  while(1){


      if(!flag){

        int i, j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++){
            FFT_In[i] = Buff[i];
        }


        // FFT and UART code


        HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(&hdfsdm1_filter0, Buff, BUFFER_SIZE);

        flag = true;
      }

    }

}

…

// Called when the buffer is completely full
void HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvCpltCallback(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter)
{
    buffer_full = true;
    HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStop_DMA(hdfsdm_filter);
    flag = false;

}
```

Also I provide some screenshots of the configuration of the module. [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PW2LjLJfOND9svsLZF9bQ5Z1Y0GvOdUc?usp=sharing]

Any help is appreciated! Also forgive me if i've done one or several gramatical/ortographic errors, english is not my first language.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? I too see odd values out from the DFDM filter.

Comment: I'm no longer working with this and it was a while ago so I don't really remember but I'm quite sure that it didn't end working as it was supposed to. However there is a github repo that maybe helps you: https://github.com/y2kblog/NUCLEO-L476RG_DFSDM_PDM-Mic (I assume this guy made it work as expected) @KevinParker

Answer (score 0):

Good question! What have you been using to configure the peripherals? CubeMX or directly with code?

> The microphone (I pretend to work in stereo mode) sends PDM data and I use the DFSDM module get the microphone data in PCM format.

What do you mean "I pretend to work in stereo mode"? Do you have two mics with L/R switches set accordingly? Just filling in one channel?

> The clock frequency that is sent to the microphone is the Output Clock. I've configured the clock to use the system clock as source (80MHz) with a 125 divider, so I'm sending a 640KHz signal to the microphone.

Looking at the datasheet, that should be okay. With that, your calculated max output rate is ~12k samples per second.

> I use channel 0 with PDM/SPI input from ch0 and internal clock mode.
> I use DMA from peripheral to memory with word data width and in circular mode (which, as far as i know, involves that once the buffer is full, new data is written at the beginning of the buffer)

That sounds alright as well.

> use the Filter0 with regular data injection from channel 0 in continuous mode and I have enabled both DMA and fast mode. I use a Sinc3 filter with Fosr = 16 and Iosr = 1. As far as I know and using table 159 from the RM0351, this involves that I have values between +/- 2^(log2(16^3)) = +/- 4096. That's 12 bits + 1 bit for the sign.

Based on what you say here, indeed, you should be seeing values within +/- 4096. What kind of values are you getting?

> The values I get in the buffer that DFSDM uses for storing the data aren't in this range. However, I've read that the resolution of the DFSDM is up to 31 bits but the resolution of the output data is only up to 24 bits. I really don't understand this, but I suppose that I haven't to be concerned about that because I use 13 bits. I also asume that the right bit shift option is for cases where the DFSDM resolution is grater than 24 bits. Am I correct?

Yes, you are correct - the peripheral can output only 24 bits, so if the resolution of the internal data is higher than that, it has to be right shifted to be fitted appropriately.

Is there any more information that you can provide that can help us troubleshoot you the issue? Source code or CubeMX screenshots are welcome.

My guess would be the fact that you are feeding a 13-bit signed integer into a 32-bit signed buffer will mess up your values - you'd have to properly convert the number. That's why it might be easier to configure your DFSDM to output 16-bit ints and work with them.

Comment: Hello @Nick I updated the question adding some information!